# navigate vim split screens when lots of files have been opened

Tags: linux, vim, split-screen

at a time I will have more than 12-15 file opened as horizontal split screens in vim. but I will be working only on one. In order to jump between others, I had to keep track of buffer numbers which take lot of time. I have mapped j/k to jump back and forth. but to do this I have count files opened. is there any better way to do this? 
 what I am looking at is, like vim hybrid number system is there any way to display relative buffer numbers in the status bar at the bottom ?? or better way to navigate between file opened

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. [https://vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you can change split screens with:

```
<C-W>h
<C-W>j
<C-W>k
<C-W>l
```